# Automate scripts running on GitHub?

Tags: github

I wanted to know if it's possible to automate a Python script to run once a week via a GitHub repository. Alternatively, if it's possible to make an action (such as a new file being added to a folder in the repository) trigger a script to run.

Also, can you host a webpage on GitHub (frontend and backend)? I would like to make a web client for people to interact with the results of my script (a spreadsheet).